# GitHub doesn't show commits

Tags: github

I can't understand why GitHub doesn't show my commits in profile calendar. For instance I'd committed several times in April

[image: April commit's]

but April is empty in the profile calendar

[image: empty calendar]

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: They must be merged into the master branch before they are visible. Othwise they won't show up in your log.

Comment: I believe your question shouldn't be tagged [tag:git] as it is specific to GitHub

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+count+contribution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they was made in private repositories. If so, you turn it on in profile setting. And there is also confs like show pro status and so on